# How to subclass CollectionViewCell and change subclass Identifier programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have collectionViewCell with Nib file

```
ACollectionViewCell
ACollectionViewCell.xib
```

inside my ACollectionViewCell , i dropped @IBOutlet from .xib .

I create a new sub class named  BCollectionViewCell

```
class BCollectionViewCell : ACollectionViewCell { ... }
```

I want to use my ACell and BCell inside my CollectionViewController

```
collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"ACollectionViewCell ") .....
```

The problem is here , BCollectionViewCell didnt have .xib , to setup ***ReuseIdentifier***

How can i setup my BCollectionViewCell Reuseidentifier without create new BCell.xib ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a cell without xib with

```
collectionView.register(BCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BCollectionViewCell ")
```

But it should be completely created programmatically , so for your case i recommend to create `ACollectionViewCell` programmatically as you may encounter nil exceptions when you access oultets of main class `ACollectionViewCell` inside an instance of type `BCollectionViewCell`